# Is there any rule or standard for the names that should go on the mailbox and door bell?

Tags: germany, relocation, names

In Germany my family name goes on the door bell name tag (`Türklingel Namensschilder` or `Klingelschilder`) and mailboxes name tag (`Briefkasten Namensschild`) for identification purposes and for the correct handling of the post office mail. In my country there are multiple family names (some from the mothers family and some from the father family) and not only one, so I might be receiving mail using abbreviated forms or just the name followed by the last family name.

Is there any rules/laws regarding the naming system on these tags? If I do abbreviate will be postal worker allowed to place in mail for me? If me and my wife have the same surnames[last names] should I place the standard abbreviated name and family name separated by slashes to denote different persons regardless of the family name being the same?

Comment: I have no idea about any laws regarding this, but anecdotally I'd say you're over thinking it. Put as many names in as many variants on there as necessary to make it clear to the postal worker where your mail goes. If that means you may have to write your name in three different variations, then that's fine.

Comment: You could visit some random apartment building for inspiration (or several – in some of them, name tags are made by the property management and therefore somewhat consistent). There are lots of common variants: surname only, full name, initials plus surname, … Otherwise, I agree with @deceze.